# How to set variable to a reserved word in Mulesoft 4

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft

In my the payload I have a type field and I want to set a variable that has the value of it. I get an error "Invalid input "type", expected arrayValueSelector or valueSelector (line 1, column 12)".

[image]

Comment: can you show us how your input payload looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reserved word if coming as input should be enclosed in quotes like

## [payload.'type']

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the attribute name to avoid that error:

```
#[payload[0].'type']
```